# Prove or disprove: If $f$ is continuous and differentiable in $[a,b]$ then $a$ is a local minimum or a maximum point in $[a,b]$.

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Prove or disprove: If $f$ is continuous and differentiable in the interval $[a,b]$ then $a$ is a local minimum or a maximum point in $[a,b]$

I'm trying to disprove by giving a counterexample, any suggestions?

Comment: How coud it be diff in $[a,b]$ when the function was not defined else where? I mean $(a,b)$??

Comment: @BabakS. I may didn't get ur question. but this is an accurate phrasing of the question. maybe we need a counter example to emphasis your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  function $$f(x) = -2xe^{-x^{2}}$$ is continuous and differentiable on all of $\Bbb{R}$, so it is continuous on the subinterval $[-2,2]$. But you'll find $f(-2)$ is neither a local min nor a local max on that interval.

Comment: How do you think about an example like this?

Comment: I figured a function that spiked up and down in the middle of the interval and flattens at the ends would do the trick. I know $e^{-x^{2}}$ flattens at the end, so I multiplied it by $-2x$ to make it spike up and down in the middle. The same logic would work for something like $x\cos(x)$. Hope that helps!

Comment: awesome man, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=\sin(x), ~~x\in[0,\pi], f(x)=-x,~~x\in(-\infty,0)$ for example. What can we say about $x=0\in[0,\pi/2]$?

Answer (score 0):

What about $f(x) = x^3 \sin(1/x)$ ?

$f(0) = 0$, but there is positive and negatives points in every $[0,\epsilon[$

Comment: Did u mean you defined $f=0$ at $0$?

Comment: @Hrodelbert: oups ! use $x^3 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ then instead.

Comment: @BabakS. : Yes, it's the natural value as the function become continuous then

Comment: @Tryss can u explain why it doesn't have local maximum or minimum in a?

Comment: because for every interval $[0,\epsilon]$ there is positive and negative value of $f(x)$ (take $\frac{1}{2k\pi+\pi/2}$ and $\frac{1}{2k\pi-\pi/2}$: hence 0 is not a maximum and not a minimum on $[0,\epsilon]$